Can an axiomatic system be consistent if the system obtained by removing some axioms isn't?
I asked another question before, where I asked if this:
$\mathrm{Con}(\mathcal S + \neg\mathrm{Con}(\mathcal S))$
Could be true for some axiomatic system $\mathcal S$.
I was told that it's totally possible, since $\mathcal S \not\vdash \mathrm{Con}(\mathcal S)$. At the same time, I'm wondering if it's possible for an axiomatic system to be consistent if a subset of its axioms isn't.

As the answer below says, the answer to the question in your title is "no" for fairly straightforward reasons. Can you explain a little more why you think your question is related to the fact that $S + \lnot \mathrm{Con}(S)$ may be consistent? It's not totally clear to me and I think you may have a misconception somewhere which is your "real" question.

@IzaakvanDongen well, if a statement is independent from a certain system of axioms, you should be able to add it or its negation to the axioms without affecting the consistency of the system, right? So, since $\mathrm{Con}(\mathcal S)$ is independent from a consistent system $\mathcal S$, I should be able to add $\neg\mathrm{Con}(\mathcal S)$ to the axioms without affecting its consistency.

@Elvis Yes, but what does that have to do with the question in the title? In this case, the "system obtained by removing some axioms" (i.e. $\mathcal S,$ obtained by removing $\sf\lnot Con(\mathcal S)$ from $\sf\mathcal{S} + \lnot Con(\mathcal S))$ is consistent.

@spaceisdarkgreen say $\mathcal S$ is PA. Its consistency can be proven in ZFC. Now, the system $\mathcal S + \neg\mathrm{Con}(\mathcal S)$ is still consistent, as you said, but doesn't it contradict the fact that $\mathcal S$ is consistent in ZFC?

@Elvis No. Just because $\sf \mathcal S + \lnot Con(\mathcal S)$ is consistent doesn't mean it is right (i.e. that $\mathcal S$ is actually inconsistent).

This cannot happen.
An axiom system is inconsistent if it proves everything.  If it proves everything, it also proves the axioms that you claim you can add that would make it consistent.
That is, you want $S$ inconsistent, and $S+T$ consistent.  But since $S$ is inconsistent, it already proves everything in $T$.
Another way to see it: any valid proof in $S$ will work just as well as a proof of $S+T$; there's no rule that says that a proof has to use all the axioms.  So if $S$ proves everything, so does $S+T$.

That's what I was thinking. At the same time, since $\mathrm{Con}(\mathcal S)$ is independent from $\mathcal S$ because of the second theorem of incompleteness, you should be able to add it or its negation to the axioms without affecting the consistency of the system.

Correct, that's what “independent” means in this context.

but the problem is that if I add to the axioms $\neg\mathrm{Con}(\mathcal S)$, that is independent from $\mathcal S$, I get an inconsistent system, right?

$S+\lnot \operatorname{Con}(S)$ is only inconsistent if $S$ can prove $\operatorname{Con}(S)$  (or if $S$ was inconsistent to begin with).  But as you found out from your earlier question, it's quite usual that $S$ cannot prove  $\operatorname{Con}(S)$.

so $\mathcal S + \neg\mathrm{Con}(\mathcal S)$ is or isn't consistent?

Careful, you shouldn't confuse “$T$ is consistent” with “$T$ can prove that $\operatorname{Con}(T)$ is true”.  It might be that $T$ is consistent but you can only prove it within some more powerful system.  For example, ZF proves that PA is consistent, but PA doesn't prove that PA is consistent.  So $PA + \lnot\operatorname{Con}(PA)$ is still consistent, although it's weird. You might want to check out Franzén's book on inexhaustibility.

No problem! And good luck in your studies.

thanks. Just another question, if it isn't a bother. You said that $\mathsf{PA}+\neg\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$ is consistent, since PA doesn't prove its own consistency, of course. But since ZFC can prove $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$, wouldn't $\mathsf{PA}+\neg\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$ be inconsistent in ZFC?

@Elvis No, what you can conclude from the fact that $\sf ZFC$ proves $\sf Con(PA)$ is that $\sf ZFC + \lnot Con(PA)$ is inconsistent. I'm not sure what you mean precisely by "$\sf PA + \lnot Con(PA)$ is inconsistent in $\sf ZFC$" but in fact $\sf ZFC$ proves $\sf Con(PA + \lnot Con(PA))$, so at least for what I think is the most straightforward interpretation of that statement, it's false.

It is not possible for a consistent axiomatic system to have an inconsistent subsystem - a proof of an inconsistency in the subsystem would also be a proof of an inconsistency in the containing system. Remember that the consistency statement $\mathrm{Con}(S)$ formed following Gödel's approach is only equivalent to the consistency of $S$ when you interpret $S$ in the standard model. An extension $S'$ of $S$ can have models containing an element $p$ that behaves exactly like a Gödel encoding of a proof of $0 \neq 0$ as far as $S'$ can tell, but $S'$ can't tell that $p$ is actually not a finite natural number. So $\lnot\mathrm{Con}(S)$ holds in those models, but the witness $p$ to the inconsistency of $S$ is not a finite natural number, so the apparent proof of inconsistency is illusory.

The answer to your question is no.  An axiom system is inconsistent exactly when it proves some contradiction.  The Compactness Theorem tells us that proof has to use only finitely many axioms.  Therefore, if some subset of $\mathcal S$ proves a contradiction, some finite subset must prove that same contradiction, in which case $\mathcal S$ itself also proves that contradiction and must also be inconsistent.

How is the compactness theorem relevant? If a subset of $S$ admits a proof of  a contradiction, then that same proof is also a proof in $S$ of a contradiction.

@RobArthan You’re correct, of course, that it’s not necessary to refer to the Compactness Theorem, but I think it makes things a little more concrete and therefore a little easier to understand.
